# Angular: How to know what is causing this huge space allocation in html file in Source Map Explorer

Tags: angular, optimization, build, source-maps

I am trying to optimize an angular application and I am using Source Map Explorer to identify which part of my application is taking a lot of space.

Command to build my angular project:

```
ng build --configuration=dev --source-map
```

Configuration for dev:

```json
"dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": false,
                  "inlineCritical": true
                },
                "fonts": true
              },
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "serviceWorker": true
            },
```

Command to create Source Map Explorer:

```
source-map-explorer dist/**/*.js
```

When I go to source map explorer output, I found that around 4mb is taken by an html file which is just a sidebar component.

[image]

I need to know what's causing this space allocation in an html file?

Thanks

Comment: try building the app in production config. It just makes more sense and maybe this huge piece would be stripped out

Comment: @Andrei It's actually not the local dev environment. It's supposed to have the same configurations as the production environment but just for testing. 
Do you have any suggestion for configurations or did you see anything like this before?